# Hive on EMR | Number of mappers | Hive pointing to S3 Location

Tags: amazon-s3, hive, amazon-emr

Q1.
I have a hive table 'rates' pointing to S3 location that contains only two files of size 677MB each : [image: Rates Table]
When I am counting total number of records, it is just launching 2 mappers. Why it is so? How can I increase it?
[image]

Q2. I have another hive table 'demo_tb1' pointing to S3 location that contains 4000 files of size just 2.7 KB: 
[image]
When I am counting total number of records, it is just launching 1 mapper. And it is taking too much time to execute. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The number of mappers that get launched for the job is primarily decided by the **size of data** that you operate on. As you have observed having 4000 files of 2.7 KB each launched only 1 mapper whereas Having 2 files of 677 MB each launched 2 mappers.

**How can you increase the number of mappers?**

There is one config named as `mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize`. You need to decrease the value of this config to some smaller number.

**How do I know what is the current value of this config?**

Simply run this command without specifying a value like this in the hive editor.

```
SET mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize;
```

This would give the result in Bytes.

**How do I change the value for this config?**

Run this command to change it to 16MB for example.

```
set mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize=16777216;
```

**Note:** Please change the value according to the parallelism (number of mappers) that you want to have.

I hope this helps.